# How does a browser handle a <template> tag VS a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

I have been reading the documentation on the `<template>` tag, and I can't seem to understand how it is different from simply using a `<div>` that is `display: none;`

Documentation: [template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

`<template>` example

```
<template id="productrow">
  <tr>
    <td class="record"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

VS
`<div>` example

```
<div id="productrow" style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td class="record"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

1. On a low level, how does the browser handle these 2 examples differently?
2. Are certain JS methods or HTML attributes different or not available?

PS: I am aware of browser compatibility differences

Comment: `template` can go in `head` whereas `div` cannot

Comment: `div` also has `align` and `template` has `content`.

Comment: Also, `<template>` can hold elements which would be invalid inside of a div (like in your example).

Comment: You're asking about low-level, but from a high-level perspective: `<template>` allows writing good semantic code, because it's clear that it's not a regular page element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider:

```
<template>
  <style>
    body: { background-color: black; }
  </style>
  <script>
    alert('hello');
  </script>
  <audio src="alert.wav" autoplay></audio>
</template>
```

And:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <style>
    body: { background-color: black; }
  </style>
  <script>
    alert('hello');
  </script>
  <audio src="alert.wav" autoplay></audio>
</div>
```

Are these going to behave the same when the browser renders them? (Spoiler: no.)

To address your specific questions, though:

> 1. On a low level, how does the browser handle these 2 examples differently?

For one, the HTML inside a `<template>` does not become DOM elements that are children of the `<template>`. It becomes children of an "inert" DocumentFragment (indirectly; this is a simplification) where they exist as nodes but do not "do" anything, as in the example above.

In addition to being "inert," the template contents have no "conformance requirements." Your `<tr>` example above is a good one. See what happens here:

```js
const template = document.querySelector('template');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log('template.innerHTML is', template.innerHTML);
console.log('div.innerHTML is', div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<template>
  <tr>
    <td class="record"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</template>

<div style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td class="record"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

In a normal document, a `<tr>` can't be a child of a `<div>`, so the browser just removes it. In a `<template>`, that requirement doesn't exist. You would find the same with, say, `<div style="{{myStyle}}">`. In a document, the browser would throw away the `style` attribute because its value is invalid; in a `<template>` it would not. This is what makes `<template>` useful for, well, templating.

If you want to know more about how `<template>`s are rendered, I suggest reading the [section about it in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element). It's not easy reading, and parts may be incomprehensible, but you stand to learn a lot.

> 2. Are certain JS methods or HTML attributes different or not available?

The `<template>` element has the `content` attribute, which points to the DocumentFragment discussed above.

Comment: While correct, of course, you should also point out the other differences that were mentioned in the comments already.

Comment: Does `display: none` cause content to "not" be added to the "dom" tree? Or is it still rendered but not "physically" on the page?

Comment: `display: none` affects only the appearance of an element. It still participates in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Elements inside of `<template>` can't be found by any selector in JS, so you can't accidently find them and to extract them you have to use the `content` property of the [HTMLTemplateElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement) using something like:

```
var clone = document.importNode(templateElement.content, true);
```

Also every `<style>`, `<audio>/<video>/...` or `<script>` is parsed on page load, but doesn't run until you clone it to into the main DOM.

Answer (score 2):

I found an article that explains all the differences in detail:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

I realize now that the `<div>` example was actually, kind of a polyfill used in older browsers and has to be severely hacked to make it work as expected.

Thanks for everyone's help.